# Add a middleware for only one single method in the controller - Laravel

Tags: laravel

There is a middleware called `ageCheck` and a controller called `MyController` and it has following methods which is returning views.

```
index();
show();
edit();
```

How can I add a route middleware for only edit method in the `MyController`?

I tried this, but it doesn't work!

routes.php:

```
Route::get('/edit', [
  'middleware' => 'ageCheck',
  'MyController@edit'
]);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add it at the end of the route that you define:

```
Route::get('/edit', 'MyController@edit')->middleware('ageCheck');
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware#registering-middleware)

Another option would be to put it in the construct of your class:

```
class Mycontroller {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('ageCheck')->only('edit');
    }
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#controller-middleware)

Answer (score 3):

if you using laravel 5.3 and greater. try this

```
 Route::get('/edit','MyController@edit')->middleware('ageCheck');
```